# Нормализация юникода / удаление умляутов / превращение текста в читабельное и искабельное

Tags: unicode, icu

К примеру, есть городок Río Turbio: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Río_Turbio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%ADo_Turbio)

Чтобы его найти, неподготовленному пользователю надо ввести именно Río, а не более привычное Rio (предположительно, пользователь знает русский и английский). Если искать именно Rio, то ничего не найдется. Я тоже не обладаю знанием о том, что черточка вместо точки имеет значение, да и на моей клавиатуре нету нужной буквы.

Первая идея: нормализовать все до состояния NFKD через ICU и удалить мусор. Это +20 мегабайт, что для мобильного приложения как-то много, но в принципе сойдет. А дальше удаляем все от 0х300 до 0х362. Проблема в том, что от буквы Й тоже отваливается крыжек, значит выводить на экран такое уже нельзя.

Вторая идея: N-gram поиск. Я не очень представляю как сделать индекс, так что надо будет перебирать, что долго, ну раз уж лучше идей нету... Но тут будет страдать точность, к примеру в слове Słupcamiędzychodzki буква ł вообще никак не декомпозируется.

Все это должно работать на мобилочке, размер поисковой базы около 1 гигабайта. Всякие SQL использовать не хочу, так как объем текста очень большой, а база распухнет до неприличия. Есть идеи?

Comment: В сторону [транслитерации](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general) ICU ещё не копал?